# Mail server not sending email with spring bott

Tags: email

I am using spring boot locally to test email.
here is my setting in the application.properties file.

```
spring.mail.host=mail.abc.com
spring.mail.port=25
spring.mail.username=manager@abc.com
spring.mail.password=password
```

When I run the code in the debug mode.
I can see that email is delivered to mail server;
DEBUG SMTP: message successfully delivered to mail server

But don't receive this email.

Please can someone advice me where I am going wrong.

Thank you
Ish

Comment: use https://mailsnag.com SMTP server and it will show actual emails your app tries to send. If that works, it means that something is wrong with your SMTP server that sends actual emails.

Answer (score 0):

> I can see that email is delivered to mail server; DEBUG SMTP: message successfully delivered to mail server

Seems likely that the problem is downstream from Spring Boot.

##### Mail Relay

You are sending to a mail relay (=SMTP server).  Are send logs available there?

##### Spam

Ask yourself whether the email server you are sending it to includes Spam classification of the email and whether the reason you are not seeing the email is because the email looks "spammy".

There are no definitive answers for what is "spammy" since it is a game between spammers and those don't want spam.  You provide no details of what/how you are sending, so I shall guess these could be the reasons why your test email is perhaps been quarantined by a spam classifier:

- the domain you are (apparently) sending from is not bonefide
- you send very little text or suspect content
- you send only text or only HTML variations of the message
- you have no technical measures in place to minimise Spam classification: SPF, DKIM, DMARC
- your sending IP is blacklisted, or least not trusted

I would try sending to an alternate email address that is not processed by a server with any/the same spam protection.